# Finding the generators of De Rham cohomology of surface of genus two

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology

I need help finding a nice way to define coordinates on a surface of genus two and construct its De Rham cohomology ring explicitly in terms of differential forms generating it.

What I have done: I know how to construct a surface of genus two using an octagon by gluing the edges. This way, we have a vertex, four loops ($a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$), and a disk with its boundary identified by $dcbab^{-1}a^{-1}d^{-1}c^{-1}$. For a simple torus, we only have two loops, and we could just parametrize each one of them by an angle which would also give us the coordinates on the torus. But here, we have four loops, but we only need two variables to define coordinates on the space. How do I fix this?

Note: I do not have algebraic topology background, so if you're using a fancy algebraic trick or theorem, please give a geometric explanation.

Comment: Have you thought about using the fact that the genus 2 surface is a connected sum of two tori?

Comment: @Tyrone I'm not sure what to do with that

Comment: Since $T^2$ is oriented, so is the connected sum $X=T^2\#T^2$ so there is a unique generator $[X]\in H_2X$ which is compatible with the orientations on both copies of $T^2$. This sorts out $H^0X$ and $H^2X$ by duality. Then Poincare duality gives you $H^1X\cong H_1X\cong (\pi_1X)_{ab}$ and you can calculate $\pi_1X$ using the Mayer-Vietoris sequence you get from the connected sum. Represent generators by simply closed curves lying in each $T^2$ to give a basis for $H_1X$. Then take their Poincare duals to get a basis for $H^2X$. Sorry if this wasn't helpful, it was just meant as an idea.

Comment: @Tyrone did you mean calculate $H_1(X)$ using mayer vietoris (or calculate $\pi_1$ using seifert van kampen)? Also in the penultimate sentence, basis for $H^1(X)$?

Comment: I believe you are correct with both assertions (it's about a million degrees here, I've been in a 3-hour long seminar and I can't think straight). The point is to get explicit generators of $H_1X$ represented by simple closed curves and then dualise. I'm not expecting this to be what the op is looking for so I've left it as a comment.